# Unable to run Groovy commands with ProcessBuilder in java

Tags: java, file, groovy, processbuilder

```
Following is my code. I am trying to run groovy command using processBuilder in some other directory. this code is not working for groovy command but same works for java command. 


String[] str1 = {"groovy","-version"};
    File directory = new File(directory_name).getAbsoluteFile();

             System.setProperty("user.dir", directory.getAbsolutePath());

             ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(str1);
             processBuilder.directory(directory);
             Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

It is throwing Internal Server error with below error logs:
by looking on these logs it seems like that groovy command can not be run on particular directory, so i checked that one as well through command prompt and found that groovy command is working fine.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy" (in directory "C:\Users\anurag.malik.NUCDOMAIN\Desktop\Work\24-04-2017_WarDiff"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    com.yolo.controllers.fileUploadController.uploadFile(fileUploadController.java:72)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Is groovy added to the `PATH`?

Comment: Yes, it is added in System Variable path field.

Comment: Can you change to `String[] str1 = {"c:\\full\\path\\to\\groovy.exe", "-version"};` and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks @Strelok its working now by adding full path..